# Google AdMob: Why do native ad response fail with "no fill" when both banner and interstitial are OK?

Tags: android, admob, interstitial, banner-ads, native-ads

I have both banner and interstitial ads in my app, but when trying to load additional native ads which I want to use in recylerviews, the result of the load with `AdLoader.Builder(...).forUnifiedNativeAd` is always :`I/Ads: Received log message: <Google:HTML> The ad request returned a no fill for the particular slot. The error log below that says 'Malformed native JSON response' is a benign warning that will be removed in a future SDK release.`

In my understanding the `slot` is the "placement" of this particular native ad which I have populated with a correct native_ad_id. (In test this should be `ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2247696110` or `ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/3986624511`)

My problem now, is that i won't be able to test the appearance of the native ads in the way which is described in: https://developers.google.com/admob/android/native/start

Why isn't there a "guarantee" on reliable results from test Ads ?

As far as I know (and understand) I have done correct, but the result from testAds will not fill...

Code snippets:

```
fun loadNativeAds() {

    Log.i(TAG,"loadNativAds(): ")

    val builder = AdLoader.Builder(context, getString(R.string.native_ad_unit_id_station_list))
    adLoader = builder.forUnifiedNativeAd { unifiedNativeAd ->
        Log.i(TAG,"loadNativeAds: Ad loaded: ${unifiedNativeAd.headline}")
        nativeAds.add(unifiedNativeAd)

    }.withAdListener(
        object: AdListener() {
            override fun onAdFailedToLoad(errorCode: Int){
                Log.e(TAG,"loadNativeAds: The prevous native ad failed to load with error $errorCode." +
                        "Attempt to load another.")
            }
        }).withNativeAdOptions(
            NativeAdOptions.Builder()
            .setAdChoicesPlacement(ADCHOICES_TOP_RIGHT)
            .build())
        .build()

    //adLoader?.loadAd(AdRequest.Builder().build())

    adLoader?.loadAds(AdRequest.Builder().build(),5)
}
```

If I use `loadAds` I get error 0
If I use `loadAd` I get error 3

`MobileAds.initialize(this,getString(R.string.mobileads_app_id))` is called in `MainActivity` and as said, all Ad banners and interstitial are functioning properly.

Are there any (undocumented) conflicts between theese three (banner, interstitial, native) somewehere ?

RG

**2020.02.09: Follow up, more information:**

From a tip in a post (could not remember from where) was to use real ad-id's and run it on my emulator, those will be automatically marked as test. (You will get TestAd mark on the Ad). Then the error message changed to: `I/Ads: Received log message: <Google:HTML> Incorrect native ad response. Click actions were not properly specified`

Searching around in here and other places, there is not much answers... To rule out filtering in my network, I've run a test (NativeAdvancedExample), that seems to go ok.

So what am I doing wrong ?

RG

Comment: Have you tried the Sample ad unit ID for Native Advanced Video, "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1044960115"? I had a similar issue on iOS, receiving no native ads, until I switched from the sample ID for Native Advanced to the one for Native Advanced Video.

Comment: I was actually adviced to use real IDs when working on emulator, it was marked as TestAd as long I used an emulator.

Comment: I had the same problem and the solution by @pommy worked

Comment: google and flutter team really do not care about this. although this is a huge bug. I still can`t get native ads admob damit